# Delete parts of SharePoint item tracking options

Tags: list, form, item

Is there a way in SharePoint to delete out whole parts of the SharePoint item tracking options? (e.g.: I do not need the field related issues or priority)

If possible, I would also like to amend the categories:

[image]

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris is right - check for content types.  Go to List Settings (or Task List settings if you have a Task List...the settings menu is pretty much the same either way).  Then select 'Advanced Settings', then you'll come to this screen:

[image: content types enabled or not?]

If **Allow managemend of content types** is set to 'No' this means that you can not hide the **Related Issues** column.  If it is set to 'Yes' I would have expected to see a Content Types header in the screen shot you posted - then you would have clicked on the content type name (Item or Task might be the name) then you could set the column to hide.

BTW a content type is simply a collection of columns that are grouped together to be managed.

So, if you aren't using content types, go to the List Settings page->then under the 'Columns' section (like in the screen shot you posted)->click on 'Related Issues' then delete it.  It will then disappear from your form.

> If possible, I would also like to amend the categories:

-> Do this via the List Settings - under the Columns header click on e.g. Status, then you are editing the column.  You can change the categories there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a task list, you can go to list settings and choose to hide them in content types section or delete the columns all together.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for coming back to me. I cannot see any delete options. How would I get there?

Comment: If you have permissions to do so here is the path you take to get there.
List Ribbon > List Settings > Task (under the Content Types section) > select the column you want to hide/delete > (Choose hide from the radio buttons or choose to Delete the column)

Comment: Hello, I am using SharePoint Online and cannot find these columns. Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to get to the task list settings page?

Comment: Hello, No I was able to get list settings when on the list. It is SharePoint online so I'm not sure if this is different?

Comment: Yes the list settings are where you can add/remove list columns in the columns section. If you happen to have "content types" enabled via advanced settings you can add/remove/hide columns though the content type associated with the list. (in this case I believe it would be a content type called 'task').

Comment: Hi, Sorry for taking a while to get back to you but I cannot see that. When I go to list settings I just get this: